# 50cc sinnis street moped revs but does not move

Tags: moped

So basically I just had an issue with my moped. I was riding it when it suddenly wobbled and stopped. When it stopped it didn't turn off it was on but when I reved it it didn't move, am suspecting the problem is with the chain? The moped is only a year old, I recently de-restricted it maybe I've been pushing it too much that it couldn't handle it? When the issue happened I wasn't even going that fast am very confused.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does your moped have a manual clutch? Or is it driven off of a centripetal system?

Comment: its not a manual clutch it's an automatic scooter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you either have a stretched or broken belt or your centripical clutch is bad and needs replaced. The auto clutch setup on fully automatic go carts, small dirt bikea/four-wheelers, and most mopeds use a centrificle clutch system and the small plastic or rubber prices wear down or out over time and makes it see like a manual shit stuck in neutral or in part and reving.

Comment: Easy cheap fix your local lawn mower and small engine repair shop would probably stock the part you need and I'd also go ahead and replace the belt just in case. The clutch systems are the same on multiple outfits. Atvs, alot of riding mowers and almost all belt driven go karts are the same and you could check into converting it over to chain drive and can change gear ratio easy that way

Answer (score 0):

Chances are it's the belt that needs to be replaced. The same thing happened to me and it was my belt that was shredded